# SymbolicC Simplified Displayed

Tags: code-generation

How might I display a simplified SymbolicC below.

For example in the following example

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]
CWhile[COperator[Less, {i, j}],
  CAssign[i, CCall[ fun, {i}]]
  ] // ToCCodeString[#1, "Indent" -> 1] &
```

Is it possible to display it like such?

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]
fun@While[i < j,
  i = CCall[ fun, {i}]];
  ] // ToCCodeString[#1, "Indent" -> 1] &
```

Comment: So, you want `fun` to generate the first expression from the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a start:

```
ClearAll[fun, $opsPatt];
    $opsPatt = Alternatives @@ {Less, Greater, LessEqual, GreaterEqual, Equal, Unequal};
SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll];
fun[code_] :=
  ReleaseHold[
    Hold[code] //. {
      (head : $opsPatt)[x_, y_] :> COperator[head, {x, y}],
      HoldPattern[Set[lhs_, rhs_]] :> CAssign[lhs, rhs],
      HoldPattern[While[cond_, c_]] :> CWhile[cond, c]
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more complete example.

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]
ClearAll[fun, $opsPatt];
$opsPatt = 
  Alternatives @@ {Minus, PreDecrement, Decrement, PreIncrement, 
    Increment, Greater, Less, GreaterEqual, LessEqual, Equal, Unequal,
     Mod, Divide, Times, Subtract, Plus, BitShiftLeft, BitShiftRight, 
    BitAnd, BitXor, BitOr, And, Or, Not};
$head = Alternatives @@ {char, int, float, double, void};
SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll];
fun[code_] := Hold[code] //. {
    (head : $opsPatt)[x_, y_] :> COperator[head, {x, y}],
    HoldPattern[Set[x_, (head_: $head)[y_]]] :> 
     CDeclare[head, CAssign[x, y]], 
    HoldPattern[Set[lhs_, rhs_]] :> CAssign[lhs, rhs],
    (*standardmathoperator[x___]\[RuleDelayed]CStandardMathOperator[
    x],HoldPattern[RuleDelayed][test,a]*)
    conditional[x___] :> CConditional[x], 
    expression[x___] :> CExpression[x], block[x___] :> CBlock[x], 
    program[x___] :> CProgram[x], statement[x___] :> CStatement[x], 
    do[x___] :> CDo[x], for[x___] :> CFor[x], if[x___] :> CIf[x], 
    switch[x___] :> CSwitch[x], default[x___] :> CDefault[x], 
    while[x___] :> CWhile[x], cast[x___] :> CCast[x], 
    HoldPattern[RuleDelayed][x_, c___] :> CDeclare[x, c],
    HoldPattern[StringExpression][x___] :> CDeclare[x], 
    enum[x___] :> CEnum[x], pointertype[x___] :> CPointerType[x], 
    struct[x___] :> CStruct[x], union[x___] :> CUnion[x], 
    typedef[x___] :> CTypedef[x], sizeof[x___] :> CSizeOf[x], 
    return[x___] :> CReturn[x], break[x___] :> CBreak[x], 
    continue[x___] :> CContinue[x], goto[x___] :> CGoto[x], 
    label[x___] :> CLabel[x], member[x___] :> CMember[x], 
    HoldPattern[Rule][x___] :> CPointerMember[x], 
    Function[x___] :> CAddress[x], $[x___] :> CDereference[x], 
    array[x___] :> CArray[x], 
    constant[x___] :> CConstant[x],(*comment[
    x___]\[RuleDelayed]CComment[x] parentheses[
    x___]\[RuleDelayed]CParentheses[x],*)str[x___] :> CString[x], 
    include[x___] :> CInclude[x], define[x___] :> CDefine[x], 
    error[x___] :> CError[x], line[x___] :> CLine[x], 
    pragma[x___] :> CPragma[x], undef[x___] :> CUndef[x], 
    fn[t_, n_, args_, x___] :> CFunction[t, n, args, {x}]};
t = fun@program[
    include["stdlib.h"],
    include["constants.h"],
    fn[int, yGreaterX, {{int, x}, {int, y}},
     i = int[3],
     if[x < y,
      block[{
        i = int[3]
        }], block[{
        x = int[4]
        }]
      ],
     return[i]
     ]
    ];
StringReplace[
 ToCCodeString[ReleaseHold@t, "Indent" -> 1], {"\n\n" -> "\n", 
  RegularExpression["\n[\\s]*{"] -> "{"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete example.

```
ClearAll[fun, $opsPatt];
    $opsPatt = 
  Alternatives @@ {Less, Greater, LessEqual, GreaterEqual, Equal, 
    Unequal};
SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll];
fun[code_] := ReleaseHold[
   Hold[code] //. {
     (head : $opsPatt)[x_, y_] :> COperator[head, {x, y}], 
     HoldPattern[Set[lhs_, rhs_]] :> CAssign[lhs, rhs], 
     HoldPattern[while[cond_, c_]] :> CWhile[cond, c]
     }];

ReleaseHold@fun@while[i < j,
   i = CCall[fun, {i}]
   ]
```